How can I show a div on hovering a image


<div className='Popular' key={key} ref={singleMovieRef} >
              <img src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${items.poster_path}`} />
              <div className='informations'>
                <div className='infoButton'>
                  <div className='leftButton'>
                  <BsFillPlayCircleFill className='playButton'/>
                  <FiPlusCircle />
                  < AiFillLike />
                  <AiFillDislike />
                  </div>
                  <div className='rightButton'>
                    <FaCircleChevronDown />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className='titleAndOther'>
                  {titleShow(items)}
                  <p className='rating'>Rating: {items.vote_average}</p>
                  <p className='type'>Genre: {items.media_type}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>



I am here able to show a div on hover and when trying to click a button from that div I am not able to do it because after hover again the div gets hidden
The image where I want to hover and information is the div that i want to show on hover and want to able to click the buttons

              
              
                
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  
                    
                  
                
                
                  {titleShow(items)}
                  Rating: {items.vote_average}
                  Genre: {items.media_type}



.hover {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.hover img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hover:hover .buttons {
  display: block;
}

.buttons {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
<div class="hover">
  <img src="https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/8af7fbe5-2f76-4aa6-9982-1be6f88160fe/d4uoa2k-d75058da-72cb-446c-af38-dd0de4d8f7a8.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcLzhhZjdmYmU1LTJmNzYtNGFhNi05OTgyLTFiZTZmODgxNjBmZVwvZDR1b2Eyay1kNzUwNThkYS03MmNiLTQ0NmMtYWYzOC1kZDBkZTRkOGY3YTgucG5nIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmZpbGUuZG93bmxvYWQiXX0.iZzxXy0gHRbUaeOjKasJ2TZhQa5DjcY5Gp8gbpU6Ku4">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button>left</button>
    <button>right</button>
  </div>
</div>



